# How to render Twig template from database in symfony2

Tags: email, symfony, render, twig

I'm working on application written in symfony2 and I want to send email after some action/event... the problem is, that the users can define something like "email templates" which are stores in db like simple string, for example: "This is some email from {{ user }}" and I need to render body for that email which should use that template...

In symfony documentation from this link: https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/email.html#sending-emails the method for render view is $this->renderView and it expects the path to file such as "bundle:controller:file.html.twig", but my template is simple string from database...

How can I render it?

Comment: `$this->renderView()` is supposed to return a simple string. Have you tried `return "some_string"`, instead of `return $this->renderView()`, just to see what happens?

Comment: you should have a look at this bundle https://github.com/Remixjobs/RjEmailBundle, which handle exactly what you want.

Comment: Things have changed, since 2011.
For anyone bumping on this question now - please read relevant recipes from Twig documentation:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#using-a-database-to-store-templates

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#loading-a-template-from-a-string

Answer (score 38):

Twig_Loader_String is deprecated and was always designed for internal use anyway. The usage of this loader is strongly discouraged.

From the API doc:

> This loader should NEVER be used. It only exists for Twig internal
>   purposes. When using this loader with a cache mechanism, you should
>   know that a new cache key is generated each time a template content
>   "changes" (the cache key being the source code of the template). If
>   you don't want to see your cache grows out of control, you need to
>   take care of clearing the old cache file by yourself.

Also check out this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10865

---

The best way I know to load a template from a String source are:

### From a controller:

```
$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate('Hello {{ name }}');
$template->render(array('name'=>'World'));
```

as described here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#loading-a-template-from-a-string

### From a twig template:

```
{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}", {'name' : 'Peter'})) }}
```

as described here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html

Note, that the 'template_from_string' - function is not available by default and needs to be loaded. In symfony you would do this by adding a new service:

```
# services.yml
services:
    appbundle.twig.extension.string:
        class: Twig_Extension_StringLoader
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

Comment: In my case I wasn't able to send variables in template_from_string (probably, it have the same scope?), so I used {% set name = 'Peter' %} before inlude

Answer (score 21):

This should work.  Replace "Hello {{ name }}" with your template text, and fill the array that is passed into the render function with any variables that you need.

```
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
echo $env->render(
  "Hello {{ name }}",
  array("name" => "World")
);
```

Comment: I agree, a concise solution without using a side bundle.

Comment: I think this is the best solution and the best answer :)

Comment: This works. I've noticed however that custom twig extensions are not enabled by default. SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383522/twig-extension-to-be-available-in-new-twig-environment

Comment: This solution is not suitable for everyone: it doesn't load twig extensions, doesn't cache compiled templates (slower), and doesn't allow any kind of template reference: {% extends %} or {% include %}.

Comment: I've read in the comments for Twig_Loader_String (deprecated) that it will fill the cache up...

Answer (score 16):

Here's a solution that works with Symfony 4 (and possibly older versions as well, although I haven't tested it) and allows you to work with templates stored in the database the same way you would work with templates in the filesystem.

This answer assumes you're using Doctrine, but is relatively easy to adapt if you're using another database library.

## Create the Template entity

This is an example class that uses annotations, but you can use whatever configuration method you're already using.

**src/Entity/Template.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="templates")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Template
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $source;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $last_updated;
}
```

The bare minimum fields are `filename` and `source`, but it's a very good idea to include `last_updated` or you'll lose the benefits of caching.

## Create a DatabaseLoader class

**src/Twig/Loader/DatabaseLoader.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Twig\Loader;

use App\Entity\Template;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Twig_Error_Loader;
use Twig_LoaderInterface;
use Twig_Source;

class DatabaseLoader implements Twig_LoaderInterface
{
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->repo = $em->getRepository(Template::class);
    }

    public function getSourceContext($name)
    {
        if (false === $template = $this->getTemplate($name)) {
            throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Template "%s" does not exist.', $name));
        }

        return new Twig_Source($template->getSource(), $name);
    }

    public function exists($name)
    {
        return (bool)$this->getTemplate($name);
    }

    public function getCacheKey($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }

    public function isFresh($name, $time)
    {
        if (false === $template = $this->getTemplate($name)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $template->getLastUpdated()->getTimestamp() <= $time;
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return Template|null
     */
    protected function getTemplate($name)
    {
        return $this->repo->findOneBy(['filename' => $name]);  
    }
}
```

The class is relatively simple. `getTemplate` looks up the template filename from the database, and the rest of the methods use `getTemplate` to implement the interface that Twig needs.

## Add the DatabaseLoader to your service config

**config/services.yaml**

```
services:
    App\Twig\Loader\DatabaseLoader:
        tags:
        - { name: twig.loader }
```

Now you can use your database templates in the same way as filesystem templates.

**Rendering from a controller:**

`return $this->render('home.html.twig');`

**Including from another Twig template** (which can be in the database or filesystem):

`{{ include('welcome.html.twig') }}`

**Rendering to a string** (where `$twig` is an instance of `Twig\Environment`)

`$html = $twig->render('email.html.twig')`

In each of these cases, Twig will check the database first. If `getTemplate` in your `DatabaseLoader` returns null, Twig will then check the filesystem. If the template isn't available in the database *or* the filesystem, Twig will throw a `Twig_Error_Loader`.

Comment: For the same but with PDO, you could see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/recipes.html#using-a-database-to-store-templates

Comment: For those wanting to implement this, be forewarned that will make doing `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup` DB dependant... Which may break your image building processes if you are deploying through docker or the like...

Comment: You can always change your post-install script to be `cache:clear --no-warmup`, but this is something to be aware of...

Comment: you must be now to control cache

Answer (score 11):

Clone the native `twig` service and replace the filesystem loader with the native twig string loader:

```
<service id="my.twigstring" class="%twig.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="my.twigstring.loader" />
    <argument>%twig.options%</argument>
</service>        
<service id="my.twigstring.loader" class="Twig_Loader_String"></service>
```

Usage example from within a controller:

```
$this->get('my.twigstring')->render('Hello {{ name }}', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

Comment: As from Symfony2.2 you can simply add a new loader defining the service and tagging it with twig.loader tag. This way twig  will use the Twig_Loader_Chain that will try to load template using each defined loader. Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#twig-loader

If you need to define priority for twig loaders have a look at DifaneTwigDatabaseBundle, I've made some changes in our fork at https://github.com/webgriffe/DifaneTwigDatabaseBundle (not pushed back to original repo because I still need to review the code)

Answer (score 8):

As of Twig 1.10, the Twig Engine doesn't support rendering strings. But there is a bundle available which adds this behavior called [TwigstringBundle](https://github.com/LaKrue/TwigstringBundle#readme).

It adds the `$this->get('twigstring')` service wich you can use to render your strings.

<sub>(As September '19, the current version of Twig is 2.X, and version 3 is around the corner; so this is only applies to very old versions of Twig).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do it is to use `template_from_string` twig function.

```
{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}")) }}
{{ include(template_from_string(page.template)) }}
```

See [documentation of `template_from_string`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html)

See why it is **not** a good idea to use `Twig_Loader_Chain` or `Twig_Loader_String` for that purpose on [this github issue by stof](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10865).

Comment: Sweet and simple. Time saver. Life saver. +1

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader([
    'Temp_File.html' => 'Hello {{ name }}!',
]);
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('Temp_File.html', ['name' => 'Fabien']);
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html

Comment: And still in 3.x docs [https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, This feature was [suggested](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/pull/874) to be [added](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/commit/bf3802bc6e5199b4d065b383caf3fe81203b713d) in the core of Twig as of [1.11.0](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html), but will be needed to be activated by the developper.

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 2.2 you can use the [Twig_Chain_Loader](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#twig-loader-chain) 
[How to register another (custom) Twig loader in Symfony2 environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343435/how-to-register-another-custom-twig-loader-in-symfony2-environment/15642281#15642281)

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external sites only

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to implement a CMS used by multiple parties where each party could completely customize their templates. To achieve this I implemented a custom Twig Loader.

The most difficult part was coming up with a naming convention for the templates guaranteed not to overlap with any existing templates, for example `<organisation_slug>!AppBundle:template.html.twig`. 
In case the template was not customised, the template `AppBundle:template.html.twig` would have to be loaded as fallback template.

However, this is not possible with the Chain Loader (AFAIK) because there the template name cannot be modified. Therefore I had to inject the default loader (i.e. the loader chain) into my loader and use it to load the fallback template.

Another solution would be to pass the request stack or the session to the template loader, making it possible to automatically detect the organisation, but this is difficult because the security component depends on the templating subsystem, causing circular dependency issues.

Answer (score -9):

```
  $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
        ->setBody('hai its a sample mail')
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: That's not related to the question. Please include an example using **Twig**.