# Twig extension to be available in new Twig_Environment

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2 / Twig. I have a Twig extension which, among other things, overloads the date filter to output custom date formats based on user preference.

app/config/services.yml:

```
twig.extension.static:
    class: %twig_static_extension%  # set elsewhere
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

I'm needing to initialize a new Twig_Environment in order to render templates from the database:

controller:

```
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
```

But I am finding that this new environment does not automatically include the extension.

Naturally, I can load it like so:

```
$env->addExtension(new FQCN\To\StaticExtension());
```

Is there something I can do to make the extension available to all Twig environments that might be used?

Comment: Do you really need to *overload* the date filter? It's so easy to create a new filter with Symfony2, don't bother in trying such tricky things :)

Comment: I've not had any problems with the extension itself. I have not worded the question too well. I would expect any Twig extension, defined as a service, should be available when a new Twig_Environment is instantiated, but I am finding that it is not.

Comment: In Symfony2, you don't have to care about `Twig_Environment`, your services are initialized at the back, and you use the environment as a service at container scope. If you render twig strings from a database, you can use the [twigstringbundle](https://packagist.org/packages/r1pp3rj4ck/TwigstringBundle)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ninsuo. I guess what you are saying then is that any extensions defined in the service configuration are only going to apply to the default Twig_Environment that is initialized by Symfony2, and not to any further Twig_Environments that might be used. I didn't want to implement a bundle for what seemed like a simple requirement. Might log an issue on the Twig repository. Cheers!

Comment: A native way to generate views from strings should be excellent, coupled with sandbox, to invite site's users to create their own templates and generate things without managing files. But if we look at how Twig works internally, it does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Compiler Pass and inject it to your bundle, take a took at [TwigEnvironmentPass](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TwigEnvironmentPass.php) from TwigBundle