# Display twig variable incude in php string in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on an apps with Symfony2 that create letters. The user write the contains. I want to give the user the possibility to insert dynamic variables from database such as the title, name from whom the letter is addressed.

For exemple, the user might write "Dear {{title}},". Then, when the letter will be display in the template the twig variable {{title}} will print the title (Mr, Madame, etc).

Is it possible ? And if it is, how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. 
I just need to use the replace function in twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html

The user has just to write a proper code (ew : "%title%") and in twig if there is this in one of the content, it replace it by the right entity.

```
 <p>{{ lettreContenu.contenu |replace({'%title%': membre.refTitre.titreFull, '%name%': membre.nomMbr}) }}</p>
```