# How to echo twig tags which in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, twig

I have some posts in my database. And I have Twig template. Now, I echo all posts with Twig and `{% for post in posts .. {{ post.story }} .. endfor %}`. *But, how to echo tags, that already in my database? For example:*

```
My long story {{ post_image.1 }} is about...
```

It's rendered as `My long story {{ post_image.1 }} is about...` without any changes.

**controller**

```
        $posts = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM posts, posts_assets, posts_meta, users WHERE posts.id = posts_assets.id_post AND posts.id_byurl = posts_assets.id_byurl AND posts.id = posts_meta.id_post AND posts.id_byurl = posts_meta.id_byurl AND posts.pub_author = users.id ORDER BY posts.id_bytime DESC LIMIT 3");

        $tags = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM tags");

        //posts.id, posts.id_bytime, posts.id_byurl, posts.pub_time, posts.pub_title, posts.pub_author, posts.pub_tags, posts.pub_story, posts_assets.id_post, posts_assets.id_byurl, posts_assets.images

        try {
            //$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('theme/views');
            $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($aeConfig->site()['theme'] . $aeConfig->site()['theme_views']);
            $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
            $template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.tpl');

            if ($user->isAuth()) {
                echo $template->render(array(
                    'title' => $aeConfig->site()['title'],
                    'theme_dir_static' => $aeConfig->site()['theme'] . $aeConfig->site()['theme_static'],
                    'posts' => $posts,
                    'tags' => $tags,
                    'auth' => $user->isAuth()
                ));
            } else {
                echo $template->render(array(
                    'title' => $aeConfig->site()['title'],
                    'theme_dir_static' => $aeConfig->site()['theme'] . $aeConfig->site()['theme_static'],
                    'posts' => $posts,
                    'tags' => $tags,
                    'auth' => $user->isAuth()
                ));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    Flight::route('/', 'index');
?>
```

**template**

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class="__sl--block">
            <div class="_title">
                <a href="#">
                    {{ post.pub_title }}
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="_info">
                <!-- Ð²Ð¾Ñ‚ Ñ‚ÑƒÑ‚ Ñ…Ñ€ÐµÐ½ÑŒ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð° Ñ‚ÑÐ³Ð¾Ð²... ÑƒÐ¶Ð°Ñ-->
                {% set post_tags = post.pub_tags|split(',') %}

                {% set list_tags = [] %}
                {% for tag in tags %}
                    {% set list_tags = list_tags|merge([tag.tag_title]) %}
                {% endfor %}

                {% set ptl = (post_tags|length)-1 %}
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ post.name }}</li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        {% for i in 0..ptl %}
                            {% if i == ptl %}
                                {{ list_tags[post_tags[i]] }}
                            {% else %}
                                {{ list_tags[post_tags[i]] }},
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ post.pub_time }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ post.comments }}</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ post.views }}</li>
                    <!--<li><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 17</li> no favs-->
                </ul>
            </div>

            {% set post_assets = post.images|split(',') %}
            <a href="#">
                <div class="_image" style="background: url('{{ post_assets.0 }}') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="_body">
                {{ post.pub_story|raw }}
                <div class="end"><a href="#">ÐŸÑ€Ð¾Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¶Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ‡Ñ‚ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <i>ÐŸÑƒÑÑ‚Ð¾Ñ‚Ð°...</i>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="__sl--moreblock">
        ÐŸÐ¾ÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð±Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÑˆÐµ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾ÑÑ‚ÐµÐ¹ <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide source code how you render both type of templates

Comment: Okay, 1 minute please.

Comment: This is my code (php and tpl): http://horiz.me/source/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2)

Comment: @DarkBee, Thank you, `template_from_string` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you have a twig-formatted string in your DB and you want to render it with the twig engine.

to do this you can use the [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) or [embed](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) twig functions. 
create a single-post template that gets a the post arguments and include it in your posts template.

include a post template

```
{% for post in posts .. {% include 'post.html' with {'post': post} %}  .. endfor %}
```

or use [template_from_string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) as @DarkBee suggested

Comment: You forgot about the `template_from_string` part though