# Ckeditor - using twig code within FOSCKEditor wysiwyg

Tags: twig, ckeditor, symfony4, wysiwyg

I wanted to know if it was possible to put twig code in ckeditor and that it interprets correctly the code in order to generate the HTML code.

I've already seen some configurations (using "protectedSource") that allow to put twig code within ckeditor but when I do that, the twig code is still interpreted as a string.

My goal here is to create some twig functions that I could use inside CKEditor.

Example :

Let's say that the "my_complex_table_function" function return a complex table, i would like to be able to put

```
 {{ my_complex_table_function }}
```

in CKEditor and that it returns the table in the front page.

Is that possible ?

Thanks guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2)

Comment: hm not really if i understood it correctly. My Twig function would be saved inside the CKEditor field so I won't need an entity.

Comment: I was referring to the most [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059254/446594)

Comment: oh sorry i'll give it a try !