# Execute twig var in twig current

Tags: twig

I have make a form to submit values html* example :

```
 <div><a class="btn btn-light" href="#">{{crsf_token}}</a></div>
```

My block twig page:

```
{{ container.area|raw }}
```

Is not showing the var twig submitted, how to execute twig in twig?

[image: twig demo]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2)

Comment: Hello nope, i dont use a symfony, thanks for comment.

Comment: Read the part about the [tempate_from_string](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html) - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059254/446594)

Comment: I don't understand it. You want to render the submitted information? So the content from the button comes from a form submission?

Comment: @StephanVierkant no, the variable `container.area` contains twig code which OP wants to see executed

Comment: So the first snippet (with the button) is in variable container.area? This seems very complicated. How is `crsf_token` generated? If not using Symfony, how does the application logic look like?

Comment: Well OP's is probably using a CMS system in which he/she can create extra content blocks/containers

Comment: You can try {{ container.area|nl2br }} or  {{ container.area|raw|nl2br }}