# Out putting RAW ACF values in twig/timber unto page header for SEO purposes

Tags: twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

So, from ACF I have created my own SEO fields in my custom WP theme, so I don't have to rely on a plugin, and I want to have the default values already filled out, so we don't always have be doing that unless for something specific - how do I out put those unto my page and insert them in the header at the same time? I have tried `{{post.meta_description|raw}}` and `{{ function('wp_head') }}` [timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/#function) but it just prints it on the page, what am I missing?

```
Another great {{ post.tool_brand }} {{ post.tool.type}} 
for sale, {{ post.power_type }} of power with a 
competitive price {{ post. tool_price }}!
```

[image: acf seo fields]

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container my-4">
        <head>
            {{post.meta_description|raw}}
            {{ function('wp_head') }}
        </head>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

[image: actual output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2)

Comment: @DarkBee I am not sure if it does or maybe I am not understanding something, was hoping for the solution would be easier than all that?

Comment: The output you've shown is stored in the database, by default twig will not parse "templates" that are stored in (string) variables, thus you need to tell twig, to parse the string that is stored in the variable `post.meta_description`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here seems to do exactly what I wanted it to do: `{{ include(template_from_string(post.meta_description)) }}`

ie: `<meta name="description" content="{{ include(template_from_string(post.meta_description)) }}">`