# Twig Extension For Including Templates in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm storing page code in database so that the admin will be able to rearrange sections and edit content.

I'm organizing all the code in the controller before sending a response that has all the code for the page.

I've seen this question: [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2) and it is not the same as the one I'm asking

I'd like to be able to have a code in the database like "{% include 'tmp/header.html.twig' %} and have the twig run that.

So far twig gives an error that 'Template "tmp/header.html.twig" is not defined in __string_template__59b79c6909e3d467bcae264ee8ebdf3697db94a9096b7457d0c43bac9c0d8fb1 at line 345.'

Here is a test page:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/for/conservatoire/of/music", name="test")
 */
public function test(PageRepository $pageRepo, SectionRepository $sectionRepo): Response
{
    // this page
    $page = $pageRepo->findOneByName('about');

    // html is now empty
    $html = "<html><body><h1>Hello pal</h1></body></html>";

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART
    $html .= '{% include("tmp/header.html.twig") %}';

    $variables = ['this' => 'that'];

    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader([
        'test.html.twig' => '{{ include(template_from_string(html)) }}',
    ]);
    
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
    $profile = new \Twig\Profiler\Profile();
    $context = new Routing\RequestContext();
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $routes = $router->getRouteCollection();

    $generator = new Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator($routes, $context);
    $versionStrategy = new StaticVersionStrategy('v1');
    $defaultPackage = new Package($versionStrategy);
    $namedPackages = [
        'img' => new UrlPackage('http://img.example.com/', $versionStrategy),
        'doc' => new PathPackage('/somewhere/deep/for/documents', $versionStrategy),
    ];

    $packages = new Packages($defaultPackage, $namedPackages);

    // this enables template_from_string function
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension());
    // this enables debug
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension());
    // this enables {{asset('somefile')}}
    $twig->addExtension(new AssetExtension($packages));
    // this enables {{path('someroute')}}
    $twig->addExtension(new RoutingExtension($generator));

    // I NEED ONE THAT ENABLES {%  include('tmp/header.html.twig') %}
    // so far I'm getting this error: 
    // Template "tmp/header.html.twig" is not defined in __string_template__59b79c6909e3d467bcae264ee8ebdf3697db94a9096b7457d0c43bac9c0d8fb1 at line 345.

    $response = new Response();
    
    $response->setContent($twig->render('test.html.twig', ['html' => $html]));
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    
    // sets a HTTP response header
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    
    // return response
    return $response;
    
}
```

It doesn't work even when the include is added separately like so:

```
    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader([
        'test.html.twig' => '{% include("tmp/header.html.twig") %}{{ include(template_from_string(html)) }}',
    ]);
```

Error: `Template "tmp/header.html.twig" is not defined in test.html.twig at line 1.`

Comment: Why don't you store the html code of the page directly and render it after ?

Comment: That is what I'm doing. Only that the html will contain {{asset}}{{path}} and {{include}}

Comment: This doesn't look right, not sure what you're trying to achieve. Use `return $this->render('file.html.twig', array('someData' => 'data from the db')` in your controller and pass the data to your twig file. I wouldn't store the actual twig syntax, maybe make a bool in the db and then use *if* statments in your twig to *include* another twig file...

Comment: Also, you can just store the template name as a string in the database (if this is what you're trying to achieve). Then in your twig file do `{% include 'tmp/' ~ twig_filename_passed_from_controller ~ '.html.twig' %}`..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I'm doing: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html

Comment: @Josiah, are you using Symfony? The twig engine is built in and can use the templates within your controllers, eg `$this->render(...)` etc..

Comment: When I do that the {{}} from database are not executed. They come as plain text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2)

Comment: @Josiah, don't store the twig syntax.

Comment: @DarkBee I'm already implementing that. In this case, I just want to know how to use the templating extension and do all the stuff in the controller then return a string.

Comment: Did you have a look at the custom [database loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387607/446594) then? Your ArrayLoader doesn't has access to the filesystem, thus the template can't be found

Comment: @DarkBee I'm already implementing the database loader. I have found the way out and I've posted as an answer. I only needed to add the included page in the ArrayLoader and boom!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the way to do it.
I only needed to add the page to be included to the ArrayLoader like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\VersionStrategy\StaticVersionStrategy;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Package;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\UrlPackage;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\PathPackage;
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\AssetExtension;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;

/**
 * @Route("/test/for/conservatoire/of/music", name="test")
 */
public function test(PageRepository $pageRepo, SectionRepository $sectionRepo): Response
{
    // this page
    $page = $pageRepo->findOneByName('about');

    // html is now empty
    $html = "<html><body><h1>Hello from test</h1></body></html>";

    // THIS WAS THE PROBLEMATIC PART
    $html .= '{{ include("header.html.twig") }}';

    $variables = ['this' => 'that'];

    // HERE IS THE SOLUTION -> ADD THE NEW TEMPLATE TO THE ARRAY LOADER 
    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader([
        'test.html.twig' => '{{ include(template_from_string(html)) }}',
        'header.html.twig' =>  "<html><body><h1>Hello from {{name}}</h1></body></html>",        
    ]);
    
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
    $profile = new \Twig\Profiler\Profile();
    $context = new Routing\RequestContext();
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $routes = $router->getRouteCollection();

    $generator = new Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator($routes, $context);
    $versionStrategy = new StaticVersionStrategy('v1');
    $defaultPackage = new Package($versionStrategy);
    $namedPackages = [
        'img' => new UrlPackage('http://img.example.com/', $versionStrategy),
        'doc' => new PathPackage('/somewhere/deep/for/documents', $versionStrategy),
    ];

    $packages = new Packages($defaultPackage, $namedPackages);

    // this enables template_from_string function
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension());
    // this enables debug
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension());
    // this enables {{asset('somefile')}}
    $twig->addExtension(new AssetExtension($packages));
    // this enables {{path('someroute')}}
    $twig->addExtension(new RoutingExtension($generator));

    $response = new Response();
    
    $response->setContent($twig->render('test.html.twig', ['html' => $html, 'name' => 'header']));
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    
    // sets a HTTP response header
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    
    // return response
    return $response;
    
}
```